# .net WCF : How TO debug a proxy class

Tags: .net, wcf

Any Idea, debug a WCF proxy class.

Actually I have created a Partial Class of a PROXY ... and I need To TEST & DEBUG IT.
using **TestDriven.Net**

but when I put a Break Point on my Partial Class , it's giving warning message like "**DebuggerStepThroughAttribute**" is **My Code Only**

Comment: What's the problem with the warning message?

Answer (score 2):

Use a debugger, such as VS 2008.

From what I [have read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5e30exc.aspx), the warning seems perfectly fine. Of course you only want to debug your code, not third party libaries, aren't you?

Comment: ;) Short, right to the point. So short it would be insulting... if the question would be forumated smarter. This way it is exactly right.

Answer (score 0):

I've had trouble doing this. How about creating your own channel factory class for your WCF service, so you're not using the generated proxy?

Something like

```
using (var channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IMyContract>(new BasicHttpBinding()))
{
   var endpoint = new EndpointAddress(@"http://myaddress/MyService");
   var channel = channelFactory.CreateChannel(endpoint);
   channel.MyOperation();
}
```

??

Answer (score 0):

you may just comment out the following attribute of the class, than you can step into the proxy class.
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]